# WPF small text rendering and scaling

Tags: .net, wpf, text-rendering

I need to "stabilize" the text rendering in an application when I use canvas scaling.

I have the following code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="356" Width="804">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer
        PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel" Grid.Row="0">
            <Canvas>
                <Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Canvas.LayoutTransform>
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="34" Canvas.Top="47" Height="23" Name="textBlock1" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; Ideal, Aliased" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="34" Canvas.Top="81" Height="23" Name="textBlock2" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; Ideal, ClearType" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="35" Canvas.Top="115" Height="23" Name="textBlock3" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; Ideal, Grayscale" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Grayscale" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" />

                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="310" Canvas.Top="46" Height="23" Name="textBlock4" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; Display, Aliased" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="309" Canvas.Top="79" Height="23" Name="textBlock5" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; Display, ClearType" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="ClearType" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="309" Canvas.Top="112" Height="23" Name="textBlock6" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; Display, Grayscale" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Grayscale" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" />
                <TextBlock Canvas.Left="188" Canvas.Top="157" FontSize="11" Height="23" Name="textBlock11" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; Default" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Canvas>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Height="23" Name="textBlock8" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; Default, static; Times New Roman, 11" FontSize="11" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" FontSize="11" Height="23" Name="textBlock9" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; DISPLAY, static; Times New Roman, 11" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" FontFamily="Times New Roman" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Height="23" Name="textBlock7" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; Default, static; Arial, 16" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" FontSize="16" Height="23" Name="textBlock10" Text="TK QSDFWPO Aàâéèêëîïôùûüÿçæœ; DISPLAY, static; Arial, 16" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" FontWeight="Bold" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When you paste it in the Visual Studio, press Ctrl and Scroll in designer, you will see, that the default under 15 size is blurry.

And the option `DISPLAY` of the `TextFormattingMode` does is broken if I zoom the canvas.

How to avoid this small text blurriness problem when using `ScaleTransform`?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a scaling transform on the canvas, perhaps you could try scaling the font size. It may be hard to get the text to line up though. Scaling the canvas in the manner that you are will force some interpolation to happen, and you will not be able to avoid the blurry text.

To be honest I don't see any difference in blurriness between the two screenshots.

Comment: I use scaling transform for all the objects in the canvas, not just texts, there are a graph inside. The difference is between the default and "Display" rendering modes. Updated second screenshot, but this is the browser who also blurs the image...